# RewriteRule not "greedy" enough

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to create a htaccess file that would show a simple index.html no matter what the url is.

#### Folder structure

```
/
  .htaccess
  a/
     index.html
```

When request comes to

```
/a/* or
/a
```

I would like to serve index.html

.htaccess file has

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^a(.*) a/index.html [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^a$ a/index.html [NC,L]
```

and it seams to work on my localhost, but it does not work on test  server (default Apache configuration on Digitalocean).

To me it looks like it is not "greedy" enough. What am I doing wrong?

urls I have tested

```
/a/ <- works both locally (uwamp is local engine) and remotely
/a <- works both locally and remotely
/a/anything/ <- works locally but not on server
```

Is there a way to debug this? Any logs to follow in order to see what is going on here?

Comment: Additional rule: `RewriteRule ^a$ a/index.html [NC,L]` to match /a only

Comment: nope, I still get 404 not found.

Comment: Can you provide the URLs you tested which work / don't work, local and remote?

Comment: @JanPapenbrock yep

Comment: And verify it is in root and not in a.

Comment: @anubhava did that of course. it is enabled.

Comment: @JanPapenbrock what is not in root and not in a?

Comment: @anubhava exactly what happens

Comment: @anubhava nah, still nothing, behavior is the same.

Comment: @anubhava now i get 404 in local also...

Comment: Sorry a type, try this rule in `/a/.htaccess`: `RewriteRule ^(?!index\.html)(.*)$ /a/index.html [NC,L,R]`

Comment: @anubhava I'm sorry, this is not working. Same thing

Comment: @anubhava no it does not.

Comment: ok looks like you have misconfigured hosts. Last rule I suggested works for me on Apache 2.2 and 2.4

Comment: Is there an version agnostic workaround?

Comment: Nothing to do with version actually. My suggested rule would work on any Apache version that has mod_rewrite and .htaccess enabled.

Comment: @anubhava I did not manage to make it work. Could you provide an answer, so we could discuss it?

Comment: Can you create a file called `info.php` with this code `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and then open `http://example.com/info.php` to check what is its `DOCUMENT_ROOT` value and Apache server version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160074/discussion-between-rouz-and-anubhava).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to rewrite everything in **/a/** to **index.html**, it should be enough to put .htaccess in a folder /a/

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* index.html [NC]
```

This way the rest of the website won't be affected by this rewrite.

Also, check if rewrite is enabled on Apache, since it is a clean install.
Default Ubuntu install does not enable it.